# Use RETURNING without explicitly naming the columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, sql-insert

I have a table with more than a few columns and want to return the id from the `INSERT` query using `RETURNING`. Unfortunately it seems that in this case I have to specify ALL columns

```
INSERT INTO "user" ( "id", ... ) VALUES ( DEFAULT, ... ) RETURNING "id"
```

instead of just doing

```
INSERT INTO "user" VALUES ( DEFAULT, ... ) RETURNING "id"
```

wich makes the query extremely long and rather unreadable. Can I return the ID somehow without specifying every column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure you *can*. Your second query should just work - provided that `id` has actually the first position in the table - which I doubt.

Verify with:

```
SELECT attnum
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid = '"user"'::regclass
AND    attname = 'id';
```

Doesn't mean you *should* do it, though. Except for ad-hoc calls there is only few occasions where you should *not* append a column list to `INSERT` commands.

Either way, you shouldn't be using a [reserved word](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) like `user` as table name. That's a very bad idea. A classical case of a loaded foot-gun.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce the issue. I'm running PostgreSQL version 9.1, created a simple `users` table with columns `id` and `name`.

I then ran this query:

`INSERT INTO users VALUES(DEFAULT,'jszobody') RETURNING id`

I got the `id` back without specifying the columns in the INSERT query. It appears to have just worked.

What error are you getting? What version of PostgreSQL? Have you tried reproducing in a very simple test case like this, ruling out any other issues with the query, default values, etc?

Comment: That's very strange. It must have been something else (maybe an invisble character in the query or something like that) that produced the error. It does indeed work without specifying the columns after I rewrote the entire query string.